# Multiple perspectives into a single SVG

Tags: html, svg

Is it possible to have a multiple different views into single SVG, or even just simulate that sort of effect with some clever use of groups? I wish to show different parts of a potentially very large SVG, but I'd rather avoid rendering it multiple times. Is there some sort of simple way of doing this?

Comment: Sure, you want the `<use>` tag.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? CSS can handle a fair amount of use cases

Comment: The `<use>` tag was the correct answer. No idea how I missed that in the spec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty simple to do.  You just use the `<use>` element as Robert suggests.  Here is a working example.

```css
svg {
  border: solid 1px black;
}

svg#original {
  width: 450px;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 450 300" id="original">
  <circle cx="225" cy="150" r="150" fill="orange"/>
  <circle cx="175" cy="110" r="25" fill="black"/>
  <circle cx="275" cy="110" r="25" fill="black"/>
  <circle cx="225" cy="70" r="150" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="20" stroke-dasharray="0 145 180 1000"/>
</svg>

<br/>

<!-- part of the original at the same scale -->
<svg width="150" height="150">
  <use xlink:href="#original" x="-50" y="0" width="450" height="300"/>
</svg>

<!-- part of the original at 0.5x scale -->
<svg width="150" height="150">
  <use xlink:href="#original" x="0" y="0" width="450" height="300" transform="scale(0.5)"/>
</svg>

<!-- part of the original at 3x scale (and using a different method to achieve the scaling) -->
<svg width="150" height="150">
  <use xlink:href="#original" x="-450" y="-255" width="1350" height="900"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

for standalone SVGs there is the `<view/>` element which you can use to show only portions of your graphics. try this in a standalone file.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="100" height="100">
    <view id="circleView" viewBox="0 0 100 100"/>
    <view id="rectView" viewBox="100 0 100 100"/>
    <a xlink:href="#rectView">
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45" fill="blue"/>
    </a>
    <a xlink:href="#rectView">
        <rect x="105" y="5" width="90" height="90" fill="royalblue" stroke="#53c"></rect>
    </a>
</svg>
```

just click on the cirlce to see the rect and on the rect to see the circle.

this also works if you reference your svg via `<img>`

```
<img src="your.svg#circleView"/>
<img src="your.svg#rectView"/>
```

i found this to be not working for inlined SVG. Here you can use a similar aproach. You can just change the viewBox of your SVG. In contrast to the above, viewBoxes can even be animated!

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 460 360" width="200" height="200">
  <polygon id="triangle" points="100,10,450,350,10,350" fill="#52c" />
  <circle id="circle" cx="50" cy="50" r="45" fill="#c52" />
  <rect id="rect" x="255" y="155" width="200" height="200" fill="#5c2" />

  <animate attributeName="viewBox" to="250 150 210 210" dur="0.5s" begin="circle.click" fill="freeze" />
  <animate attributeName="viewBox" to="0 0 100 100" dur="0.5s" begin="triangle.click" fill="freeze" />
  <animate attributeName="viewBox" to="0 0 460 360" dur="0.5s" begin="rect.click" fill="freeze" />
</svg>

<br/>click on any of he shapes!
```

of course you can also just set the viewBox by script...

if you want to reference different parts of your SVG, you might use the `<use>` - Element as suggested in the other answers.